# django-bootstrap3: changed theme_url but Bootswatch theme not loading?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-templates, django-bootstrap3

I'm trying to use the [bootswatch flatly theme](https://bootswatch.com/flatly/). I followed the instructions given on the documentation regarding updating the settings.

I've added the following to my project's settings.py:

```python
BOOTSTRAP3 = { 'theme_url': 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css', }
```

I've also added the following to my project's base.html template, between the `head` tags:

```python
{% load bootstrap3 %} 
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
{% bootstrap_messages %}
```

index.html template:

```python
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}

{% block content %}
Hello World
{% endblock %}
```

However, the theme is not reflected when I reload my index page.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Edit: a temporary workaround I've found is to overwrite the css loaded by django-bootstrap3 by adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css'>` to the base.html template file, but I'd much prefer a solution using only django-bootstrap3.

Answer (score 2):

Found out that this is a known issue, and has been [fixed](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/commit/a6050a692418523020ce19ae1f34f1b58ec3397b) recently in the develop branch of the django-bootstrap repository. However, the pip package hasn't been updated yet.

Temporarily fixed this by editing my venv copy of django-bootstrap3.